# the physical meaning of the parameter M of SetAZMs( A, Z, M, aFile )?

Tags: geant4

I am reading the resource code of Geant4.In 'G4ParticleHPFSFissionFS::Init' , what is the physical  meaning of the parameter M of 'SetAZMs( A, Z, M, aFile )'? Thanks! waiting your help!